# Adding Dicom Images

Tags: dicom

Is there any way to add a new series to an existing Dicom Image. i.e. We did a Brain MRI and afterwards we were not happy with the quality of a particular sequence. We then redid the sequence and now we want to put them all together under one. Is this possible ?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you want to add a new series to an existing study? Is it about dicom format or about a specific PACS?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to combine two **Series** from the same **Study** into one series.  Assigning a new `Series Instance UID (0020, 000e)` to all of the images that you want to be in the new aggregate series would do this.  Similarly, the `Series Number (0020, 0011)` for each of these images should be given a new value that is the same for all of them.  The `Instance Number (0020, 0013)` for each image should be edited to order the images so they display properly when viewed as a stack in a PACS viewer.  Note that I am assuming that all of these images have the same `Frame Of Reference UID (0020, 0052)`.  If this is not the case, then the images from the two series do not share the same coordinate system and all bets are off.  Also, if there was any patient motion between the two scans, you'd really need to do a registration to align the anatomy to a shared coordinate system so the two series could be displayed properly together.

However, I don't understand why you want to do this.  You repeated the scan, so you have a complete set of images for the scan already.  Why would you want to combine images from the repeat scan with images from the first scan which had artifacts?  What are you hoping to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I think OP meant "Is it possible to add a new series to an existing (closed?) study".